# Deserializing rest client response from wordpress.org

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress

I have a wordpress.org locally hosted on my pc.
I've installed a wordpress plugin called json-api which let you retrieve posts from your wordpress site.

I'm running the following code:

```
        var client = new RestClient(BlogArticlesUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.Method = Method.GET;
        request.AddParameter("json", "get_tag_posts");
        request.AddParameter("slug", "featured");
        request.AddParameter("count", "3");

        var articles = client.Execute<List<BlogArticleModel>>(request);
```

After executing the code, in the variable articles I have the following:
[image]

Inside the Content there are few keys but I would only like to convert 'posts' to a model in c#

How do I acheive that?

EDIT:

I have found a solution using newtonsoft for dot net

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlogArticleResponse>(articles.Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `RestSharp`, the `Content` is what gets deserialized. So, the type you pass into the `.Execute<T>` method **must be the same structure** as the response.

In your case, it will look something like this:

```
public class BlogArticleResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
    public BlogTag tag { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class BlogTag 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can then execute the request like this:

```
var result = client.Execute<BlogArticleResponse>(request);
```

For more information, have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization).

Comment: Do I need to write down all the parameters or can I just write what I need?

Comment: Yes, only what you need.

Comment: It doesn't work since the response returns an json object which has "Content" key which inside it there is the data

Comment: Are you sure you're not after the `Data` property?

Comment: Yes I'm sure since Data has one key which it's value is null so I need to use the Content instead

Comment: Hmmm. The `Data` property will hold the deserialized object, and in my example, that should work. Taking another look at your screenshot in the original question, in `Data` there seems to be list with *something* in it. Can you revert your code and check that?